# How do you query for "is not null" in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I would like to execute a following query:

```
db.mycollection.find(HAS IMAGE URL)
```

What should be the correct syntax?

Comment: Short answer: the query `{ field : {$ne : null} }` check for not-null
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Answer (score 1266):

This will return all documents with a key called "IMAGE URL", but they may still have a null value.

```
db.mycollection.find({"IMAGE URL":{$exists:true}});
```

This will return all documents with both a key called "IMAGE URL" *and* a non-null value.

```
db.mycollection.find({"IMAGE URL":{$ne:null}});
```

Also, according to the docs, $exists currently can't use an index, but $ne can.

**Edit: Adding some examples due to interest in this answer**

Given these inserts:

```
db.test.insert({"num":1, "check":"check value"});
db.test.insert({"num":2, "check":null});
db.test.insert({"num":3});
```

This will return all three documents:

```
db.test.find();
```

This will return the first and second documents only:

```
db.test.find({"check":{$exists:true}});
```

This will return the first document only:

```
db.test.find({"check":{$ne:null}});
```

This will return the second and third documents only:

```
db.test.find({"check":null})
```

Comment: According to docs, `$ne` **includes documents that do not contain the field**. Has this changed since you posted the answer? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Comment: I don't believe that has changed. When checking $ne, the value is checked in all documents, including those that don't contain the field, but $ne:null still will not match a document that does not contain the field since the value of the field is still null, even though the field doesn't exist in that document.

Comment: @TimGautier, are you saying `$ne:null` will __not__ match a document missing the field _because_ the value __is__ `null`?  Shouldn't it not match the document because the value is __not__ null?

Comment: $ne:null will not match a document that does not have that field because the value of the non-existent field is null and $ne:null is looking for fields that are not equal to null. So the answer to your questions are yes for the first and no for the second.

Comment: In the other hand, `$eq:null` help you to find those records that have missing data.

Comment: How do you just match the second document?

Comment: @TimGautier that's incorrect. Your second-to-last query will return the first and third documents. Unintuitive, but try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: @River I checked when I wrote this 3 years ago and, just to be sure, I just installed Mongo and tried it out again. It still works the same way, the answer is correct. The 2nd to last query returns only the 1st document.

Comment: @TimGautier odd, I just did the same myself and you're right. This is complete counter to what the `$ne` docs state.

Comment: @TimGautier oh I see, it's because all fields are implicitly contained with a `null` value.

Comment: @AndrewMao, I was confused about this too, until I came across the docs that explain how types are compared: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#non-existent-fields

Comment: The examples given make it really understandable how to use this. :-)

Comment: The examples given make it really understandable how to use this. :-)

Answer (score 159):

One liner is the best :

```
db.mycollection.find({ 'fieldname' : { $exists: true, $ne: null } });
```

Here,

**mycollection** : place your desired collection name

**fieldname** : place your desired field name

Explaination :

**$exists** : When  is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null. If  is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the field.

**$ne** selects the documents where the value of the field is not equal to the specified value. This includes documents that do not contain the field.

So in your provided case following query going to return all the documents with imageurl field exists and having not null value:

```
db.mycollection.find({ 'imageurl' : { $exists: true, $ne: null } });
```

Comment: `$exists: true` is redundant, `$ne: null` is enough.

Comment: This should be the best answer. `$exists: true` returns `null` values too. There has to be both `$exists: true` and `$ne: null`. It's NOT redundant.

Comment: @IsmailKattakath the `$ne: null` makes `$exists: true` — by your own explanation! Since `$exists: true` returns `null` values, and `$ne: null` filters those out, all you need is `$ne: null`

Answer (score 67):

```
db.collection_name.find({"filed_name":{$exists:true}});
```

fetch documents that contain this filed_name even it is null.

**Warning**

```
db.collection_name.find({"filed_name":{$ne:null}});
```

fetch documents that its field_name has a value $ne to null but this value could be an empty string also.

**My proposition:**

```
db.collection_name.find({ "field_name":{$ne:null},$where:"this.field_name.length >0"})
```

Answer (score 60):

In pymongo you can use:

```py
db.mycollection.find({"IMAGE URL":{"$ne":None}});
```

Because pymongo represents mongo `null` as python `None`.

Comment: This answer is python specific. Not correct.

Answer (score 21):

> Sharing for future readers.

This query worked for us (query executed from [MongoDB compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)):

```
{
  "fieldName": {
    "$nin": [
      "",
      null
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: { $exists: true, $ne: null } didn't show correct result.
Your query works good

Comment: Be careful, $nin often does not optimize over indexes

Answer (score 12):

In an ideal case, you would like to test for all three **values**, **null**, **""** or **empty**(field doesn't exist in the record)

You can do the following.

```
db.users.find({$and: [{"name" : {$nin: ["", null]}}, {"name" : {$exists: true}}]})
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to check the existence of the column in mongo compass is :

```
{ 'column_name': { $exists: true } }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it assumes the field genuinely was never persisted, but the OP seems to indicate (from the headline) that it could exist but be set to null explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that has not been mentioned, but that may be a more efficient option for some (won't work with NULL entries) is to use a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) (entries in the index only exist when there is something in the field).  Here is a sample data set:

```
db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544540b31b5cf91c4893eb94"), "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/foo.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544540ba1b5cf91c4893eb95"), "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/bar.jpg" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544540c51b5cf91c4893eb96"), "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/foo.png" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544540c91b5cf91c4893eb97"), "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/bar.png" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544540ed1b5cf91c4893eb98"), "otherField" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544540f11b5cf91c4893eb99"), "otherField" : 2 }
```

Now, create the sparse index on imageUrl field:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex( { "imageUrl": 1 }, { sparse: true } )
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Now, there is always a chance (and in particular with a small data set like my sample) that rather than using an index, MongoDB will use a table scan, even for a potential covered index query.  As it turns out that gives me an easy way to illustrate the difference here:

```
db.foo.find({}, {_id : 0, imageUrl : 1})
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/foo.jpg" }
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/bar.jpg" }
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/foo.png" }
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/bar.png" }
{  }
{  }
```

OK, so the extra documents with no `imageUrl` are being returned, just empty, not what we wanted.  Just to confirm why, do an explain:

```
db.foo.find({}, {_id : 0, imageUrl : 1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 6,
    "nscannedObjects" : 6,
    "nscanned" : 6,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 6,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 6,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "server" : "localhost:31100",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

So, yes, a `BasicCursor` equals a table scan, it did not use the index. Let's force the query to use our sparse index with a `hint()`:

```
db.foo.find({}, {_id : 0, imageUrl : 1}).hint({imageUrl : 1})
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/bar.jpg" }
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/bar.png" }
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/foo.jpg" }
{ "imageUrl" : "http://example.com/foo.png" }
```

And there is the result we were looking for - only documents with the field populated are returned.  This also only uses the index (i.e. it is a covered index query), so only the index needs to be in memory to return the results.

This is a specialized use case and can't be used generally (see other answers for those options). In particular it should be noted that as things stand you cannot use `count()` in this way (for my example it will return 6 not 4), so please only use when appropriate.

Comment: text fields are always sparse indexes, you don't have to specify that explicitly. just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.<collectionName>.find({"IMAGE URL":{"$exists":"true"}, "IMAGE URL": {$ne: null}})
```

Comment: Is this a valid Json document?  Two properties with the same name in the query document.  Not sure how you would build that in memory if you had to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $and and $exists with $nin for finding the scenario for not null value for the key.

> use dbname
> db.collectionname.find({$and : [{key : {$exists : true}},{$nin : [null,'',undefined]}]});

Since a value can either be present or not present.
For that case $exists will work to check the value. And for the case where value exists to check the details of that, $nin is used to exclude undefined, null and empty string.

Answer (score -5):

Thanks for providing a solution, I noticed in MQL, sometimes $ne:null doesn't work instead we need to use syntax $ne:"" i.e. in the context of above example we would need to use `db.mycollection.find({"IMAGE URL":{"$ne":""}})` - Not sure why this occurs, I have posted this question in the MongoDB forum.

following is the snapshot showing example:

[image]

Comment: Please consider to post your answer with text instead of screenshot. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: BTW take a look on data type https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: The screenshot is showing that you have empty strings saved in the DB. Those may not be useful, but they're also not null, so it's working as expected.

Comment: `{$ne: null}` checks for the field value is not `null` meaning all documens that have the field and the value will come up in the query. if you use `{$ne: ""}` checks that the field exists and is not equal to the empty string `''`. If you whether want to check if the field exists you can use {fieldName:  {$exists:true}}