# MongoDB equal to

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to run a MongoDB query and return those records where a field is null (more specifically None in pyMongo). So it has to be equal to null.

I know this is not equal to:

```
{"firstName": {"$ne": None }}
```

I can't find the equal operator in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057196/how-do-you-query-this-in-mongo-is-not-null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{"firstName":{ $type: 10 } }  should give you what you want

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls

Comment: +1 not for the answer, but for the link that covers all possibilities. It'd be good to have concise version of it summarized in answer directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find records having firstName defined in record with value None defined:

```
db.testcoll.find({$and: [{"firstName": None}, {"firstName": {$exists: true}}]})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly it should be just:

```
{"firstName": None}
```

---

With yours you are getting all the documents that have a value different of `None`.
`{"firstName": {"$ne": None }}`

Comment: I think this matches documents with no `firstName` as well; not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{"firstName": { "$exists": false }}` to find records where there's no such field.

Comment: But it would find fields where firstName doesn't even exist.

Comment: Indeed. I've just upvoted answer with link to FAQ which cover all of possibilities.

Comment: Yup, very nice and elegant solution. I liked it :)