# How do you only select MongoDB documents that have a sub-field, using the aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, exists

How do I filter out documents from a mongo collection that don't have a sub field, when using aggregation?

The collection looks like this:

```
{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("adasdasd"),
  "obj": { "a": 1 }
},

{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("ergergerg"),
  "obj": { "b": 2 }
},

{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("adasdasd"),
  "obj": { "a": 3, "b": 4 }
},
```

**How would I use the aggregate() function to only select documents where the "obj" field contains the "b" subfield? The result should look like this:**

```
{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("ergergerg"),
  "obj": { "b": 2 }
},

{ 
  "_id": ObjectId("adasdasd"),
  "obj": { "a": 3, "b": 4 }
},
```

I realize that I can use find() and $exists, But I am looking for a solution using aggregate(). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so, what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
$match: {'obj.b': { $exists: true, $ne: null } }
```

Take a look at the [$match stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

> Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the
>   specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.
>
> The $match stage has the following prototype form:
>
> { $match: {  } }

And the [$exists operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html):

> $exists Syntax: { field: { $exists:  } }
>
> When  is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the
>   field, including documents where the field value is null. If 
>   is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the
>   field.

Related question: [How do you query for "is not null" in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057196/how-do-you-query-for-is-not-null-in-mongo)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Turns out, I was using $limit before $match and wasn't getting any results. Thank you!