# how to fetch both isActive true and false

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whats wrong with my code? I want to get both `isActive:true` and `isActive: false` in just 1 api

This is my `controller course.js`

```
const Course = require ("../models/Course")

    module.exports.getAllCourses = () => {
        return Course.find({isActive: true, :false}).then(resultsFromFindActive => resultsFromFindActive)
    }
```

This is my `routes course.js`

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const auth = require("../auth")
const CourseController = require("../controllers/course")

    router.get('/active', (req, res) => {
        CourseController.getAllCourses().then(resultsFromFindActive => res.send(resultsFromFindActive))
    })
```

Comment: What is `Course`? Some model of some DB/ORM?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to get all courses where isActive is not null?

Comment: Even i changed it to !null.. the data that being fetch are all that isActive:true

Comment: I guess you are using mongoose (mongoDB) and **Course** is a schema. If so, you can change the find method as `.find({})`.

Comment: @FoxcyLoxcy Are you sure you have some records with `isActive: false`? :)

Comment: yes i have records with both isActive: true and false

Comment: So why filter on isActive? Remove it to find all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{isActive: true, :false}` is not a valid JavaScript syntax

Use [`$or` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html)

```
Course.find({ $or: [{ isActive: true }, { isActive: false }] })
```

Or [`$exists` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

```
Course.find({ isActive: { $exists: true } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the answer here:
[How do you query for "is not null" in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057196/how-do-you-query-for-is-not-null-in-mongo)

```js
Course.find({ isActive: { $ne: null } })
```

In this case you'll query for non-null values in `isActive`