# Check for non-existing field in lookup pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to check if a field is not existing inside `lookup` expression? The answers in similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057196/how-do-you-query-for-is-not-null-in-mongo) are not helpful (e.g. `{$eq : null}` or `$exists:true`).

For example, I want to lookup `inventory` only if `disabled` is not existing.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "inventory",
      let: {item: "$item"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: ["$sku", "$$item" ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [ "$disabled", null ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      as: "inv"
    }
  }
])
```

A playground sample is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/frvp4wsGiOP)

Comment: What do you want to happen if `"item"` and/or `"sku"` don't exist, like in your mongoplayground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$exists` outside the `$expr`:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "inventory",
      let: {item: "$item"},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {$expr: {$eq: ["$sku", "$$item"]}},
              {disabled: {$exists: false}}
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "inv"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fOwpm5LhLlK)

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
{ $match: { someField: { $exists: true } } }
```

before the look up, to filter out the documents that you do not want to look up

Comment: Match occurs for the main collection (`orders`) in this case, but I need it for `inventory`.

Comment: have you tried to $unwind the inventory from the orders and then use match to match disabled?