# MongoDB regex query with property that can be null

Tags: regex, mongodb

Writing a MongoDB regex query in Spring with a field that can be null.

I want to query documents by name and phone:

```
Query(value = "{ {'name' : {$regex:?0,$options:'i'}},
                          {'phone' : {$regex:?1,$options:'i'}} }")
Document findByFullNameOrPhone(String fullName, String phone);
```

The value I'm passing through the query for phone is ".*" in an attempt to match everything.

It works but the problem is *phone* is a field that can be null. If the document has no phone value it's not included in the query result. Is it possible to use this query to find all documents in the database, even if the document does not have a value for phone?

Comment: Why to use Regex? Use something like this: `db.mycollection.find({"IMAGE URL":{$ne:null}});` More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057196/how-do-you-query-for-is-not-null-in-mongo)

Comment: Because it's not only used to find all, I also want to be able to find documents where name and/or phone match the value I pass through the regex.

Comment: Pretty sure `"$regex"` will only try to match strings.  Is replacing `null` with `""` (empty string) in the docs an option?

Answer (score 0):

Just add null check.

```
Query(value = "{
  'name': {'$regex': ?0,'options': 'i'},
  $or: [
    {'phone': null},
    {'phone': {'$regex': ?1,'options': 'i'}}
  ]
}")
Document findByFullNameOrPhone(String fullName, String phone);
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B8i95oU7k_I)